# Add an aditional space to xrange and yrange

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to plot multiple files using a Gnuplot script.
However, I'm having some trouble to make it perfect.

---

My actual plots are something like that: 
[image: my actual plot]

However, the linepoints plot is touching both the x-axis and the y-axis.
Therefore, I want to add extra space on `xrange` and `yrange` and get
[image: my desired plot]
which does not touch my axis.

---

I could to it manually using `set xrange` and `set yrange`.
However, I need to plot more than 100 different files, and it will be very time-consuming to do so.

There is some manner to automatically increase the size of `xrange` and `yrange` by some units?

My Gnuplot code is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

set terminal epslatex size 7.5,3 standalone
set output 'pareto.tex'

set style fill solid 0.8
set ytics nomirror
set xtics nomirror

set grid lc rgb "#F2F2F2"

set xlabel 'Z_1'
set ylabel 'Z_2'

set xrange [170:215]
set yrange [7:40]

set style line 1 lt rgb "#000000" lw 12 pt 7 pointsize 3

plot "../exact.dat" using 1:2 title '$aug\,\epsilon$-CM' with linespoints ls 1

unset output

set output # finish the current output file
system('pdflatex --interaction=batchmode pareto.tex')
unset terminal

system
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `set offset`.  See the documentation for a full description.
Example:

```
set multiplot layout 3,1

# Default placement
plot 'silver.dat' with lines

# Additional whitespace combined with auto-extenstion to nearest ticmark
set offset 20,20,20,20
replot

# Additional whitespace with no auto-extension to nearest ticmark
set xrange [*:*] noextend; set yrange [*:*] noextend
replot

unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you @Ethan, I really never saw this `offset` parameter.